# What happens to trades that don't settle due the delisting of a the shares

Tags: trading

I sold Debenhams shares on the 8th of April and they got delisted on the 10th. I understand that there is a T+2 settlement period but in this case they fell on the same day.

Is there a procedure to follow and will I still receive cash regardless of what happens with the company?

Comment: Have you confirmed your trade actually didn't settle? Do you still have those shares in your account?

Answer (score 1):

If you sold the shares then the delisting has no effect on you.  That problem belongs to the guy who bought the shares.

Comment: I think OP may not understand that shares of unlisted companies don't disappear.  They are naturally a lot less liquid, but still represent the same ownership fraction as they ever did.